# arc forbids explicit message send of retain

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Xcode found one issue **ARC forbids explicit message send of retain** on

```
_photo = [photo retain];
```

Changing it to

```
_photo = [photo];
```

doesn't work

and I don't want to use -fno-objc-arc to disable it.

Is there some other way?

Comment: `_photo = [photo];` is invalid use `_photo = photo;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 _photo = [photo];
```

is invalid.

Use

```
 _photo = photo;
```

*The compiler using ARC is intelligent enuogh to understand what you want to do, retain or copy or release. NO need to use retain. And your statement was syntactically wrong.*

Answer (score 4):

If you want to leave ARC on, just do `_photo = photo;` no need for the brackets. As long as _photo isn't weak, (has a `__weak` in front of the declaration) ARC will insert a `retain` call for you!

Answer (score 1):

ARC puts in the necessary retain and release messages for you.  You just do the assignment

```
_photo = photo;
```

and everything wil be fine.

Answer (score 1):

> xCode founds one issue ARC forbids explicit message send of retain...

`-retain` was deprecated with the release of ARC.  It is now a function that the compiler is required to insert, and that you are not allowed to call.  (It can, however, still be overridden).

> _photo = [photo];

Messages require a target and a selector.  You have provided only a target.  Remove the braces.  The assignment will be converted automatically to something like.

```
[self->_photo release];
self->_photo = [photo retain];
```